# R - using purrr add columns on dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm looking to use purr to create a year variable on my data sets and join them together. This example will illustrate the problem and what I have tired.

```
# files in the directory 
files <- paste0("data/file_year_", 2015:2019, ".txt")

# map
files <- paste0("data_", 2013:2019, ".csv")
lst1 <-  files %>%
           map(~ read_csv(.x) %>%
             mutate(year = str_extract(., "\\d{4}")))
```

The list now needs to be merged into a single data frame.

```
dat1 <- bind_rows(lst1, .id = 'grp')
```

However, I am getting the following error when I try to create the list:

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

I tried searching for this error and nothing as helped so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does each element of `lst1` actually contain a data frame after you run your code? You assign a value to `files` twice. Also, the year ranges are different in each version.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map_df`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(files,~read.csv(.x) %>% mutate(year = str_extract(.x, "\\d{4}")),.id = "grp")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this loop with `data.table`
You can also perform specific operations on each file if you'd like.

```
library(data.table)
lapply(list.files(pattern= paste0("data/file_year_", 2015:2016, ".txt")),
       function(x){
  your_files = fread(x)
  #your_files = somecode
})%>% rbindlist()
```